# What is the difference between Frictional non-linearity and Geometric non-linearity in FEA? (In terms of Stiffness matrix)

Tags: finite-element-method, numerical-methods

For geometric non-linearity, we know that as the geometry changes during the analysis, the global stiffness matrix changes since it already is a function of geometry of the structure.

What I want to ask is that how does including a frictional contact within my FEA causes a change in global stiffness matrix so that the analysis becomes non-linear?

According to the basic FEA courses I have taken, the global stiffness matrix doesn't appear to be a function of the contact. So is the global stiffness matrix change different from the condition where geometric non-linearity is present, as compared to where the contact non-linearity (like frictional) is present?

Comment: Friction is a contact "force". It is not a geometric parameter, nor depends on the geometry of an element but the contact surface.

Comment: Thank you telling me that, but that is not what I was asking for.

Comment: The reason I said that is because I don't think friction force has anything to do with the global stiffness matrix, which stays the same whether the force is linear or non-linear.  I could be wrong by misunderstanding the context or the question though.

Comment: @r13 it depends how you model "friction". In more complex models than Coulomb friction, there is some "stiffness" or "flexibility" between the two surfaces rather than an instantaneous change from "stuck" to "slipping".

Comment: It is not about the frictional force, it is about the contact's nature. I can even apply a frictionless contact, or rough contact (where the two faces cannot slide relative to each other), but at the same time the nature of these contacts still makes the analysis non-linear. Whereas Bonded contacts are considered as Linear. As far as my knowledge goes, the non-linearity basically means that the stiffness matrix has changed. So I am pretty much sure that the contact non-linearity has definitely something to do with the stiffness matrix.

Comment: @alephzero, exactly. If you can provide me with a detailed answer on this discussion, that would beneficial. I mean the contact normal stiffness, penetration convergence, iterations, relation to the stiffness matrix (I mean if there are any changes in the stiffness matrix because of this or not), difference between these changes and the changes brought to the stiffness matrix by geometric non-linearity ETC.

Comment: Struck and slip can be modelled in steady-state motion easily. In motion involve dynamics, the vibration could be a factor but still don't explain the need in changing the global stiffness matrix. I can only understand if the variation in the geometry of the materials in contact is considered as described by the answer provided by joojaa, however, for reason unknown, his answer was downvoted. I do wish to see how the effect of the geometric changes is formulated.

Comment: @r13, I can have the geometric non-linearity turned OFF and have a frictional/frictionless/rough contact between two faces but that would still make the analysis non-linear. I want to understand why. 
[I downvoted, btw].

Comment: I believe it depends on the nature of the load (linear/non-linear) which may cause the friction to vary in a time frame.

Comment: Friction is in its simplest form probably linear. But if you were to model it as a sort of stiffness it would be odd sort of stiffness as it resists in all directions. It removes energy from the system. So it would be like a slope that is upwards even when you travel in the other direction. So again it works only in one direction of the solver. So not linear its contribution is different in different directions. So it violates the linear nature of a springlike structure since it acts like a damper. So if you would go from force of 1 to 0.5 it would behave different from 0.5 to 1

Comment: This violates the linear requirement that configuration of the starting point does not affect the end result. Thus the solver can not use normal iterative methods as they depend on minimizing a value. But there can be many local minima.

Comment: If you are familiar with structural analysis, two good examples for non-linear responses of forces - seismic analysis and P-Delta effect. The former is a non-linear event in nature, and the latter is a second-order phenomenon. Your problem may fall in one of these types, or both.

Answer (score 0):

It does not directly have anything to do with the stiffness matrix. But the geometric constraint caused by the friction is a external force that is affected by the deformation of the object.*

Since the contact changes as the object deforms then the frictional force changes by the deformation. Again it becomes nonlinear as the problem to be solved changes over the span of the solution. In fact there need not be a friction at all just a changing contact causes the same problem.

Overall, the answer is the same whatever you add to the FEA. If it isnt a simple, small angles approximation case with simple constant forces and constrains then it is nonlinear. Linear is the special case. Most if, not all, nontrivial realword cases are nonlinear. But it can still be approximately good to do a linear FEM analysis, since nonlinear cases are hard to model correctly.

* this does not mean i can not model the a change to the stifness matrix that approximates this in some cases. But its more a varying load

Comment: Excellent answer. I didn't think about deformation caused friction or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

"Geometric nonlinearity" is a confusing term, because it can include two separate effects.

In general you can write the global stiffness matrix of the structure as the sum of *three* terms: $K = K_e + K_\sigma + K_L$.

$K_e$ is the *elastic stiffness*, resulting from the stress-strain relationships in the material. For a linear elastic material it constant.

$K_\sigma$ is the *stress stiffness* which models the fact that the internal forces in the body (arising from the stress distribution) can do work when the body deforms. A simple example is a stretched string. If you pull a guitar string sideways to pluck it, the deformed shape is (approximately) two straight segments which are not collinear, each with the same tension as in the straight string. The resultant force of the two non-collinear tension forces opposes the sideways deflection. That is equivalent to a stiffness term which is proportional to the tension in the string.

$K_L$ is the "load stiffness" which is similar to the stress stiffness, but arises because the external loads on the structure may depend on the deformations. For example a pressure load acting on structure acts normal to the *deformed shape* of the surface, not to its original shape. Another example is a structure rotating at constant angular velocity about a fixed axis, where the centripetal force acting on each particle changes both direction and magnitude as the structure moves (the magnitude depends on the distance from the axis of rotation, and the direction always points towards the axis).

An example of $K_L$ is a model of a simple pendulum. The only stiffness term is $K_L$ caused by the fact the the external force (weight) acts at a different position when the structure moves.

---

A linear analysis with small strains and small displacements ignores $K_\sigma$ and $K_L$.

A "geometric nonlinear" analysis always includes $K_\sigma$ but usually ignores $K_L$. That corresponds to assuming the the strains are (infinitesimally) small, but the rigid body motion (specifically, the rigid body rotation) of the structure can be arbitrarily large.

I don't know any common term used for "including or ignoring $K_L$" In some situations (e.g the dynamics of rotating machinery) including it is essential. In other situations it is negligible and ignored.

A friction force between two surfaces is therefore a (nonlinear) load stiffness. If the surfaces move relative to each other, the friction forces do work and the direction of the friction force depends on the relative motion. But the magnitude of the friction force also depends on the stress component normal to the surface, and when the surfaces are *not* sliding there is no work done.

So it isn't very practical to include these terms in the global stiffness matrix somehow. In practice you would apply a nonlinear *constraint* to the model of the structure to create the correct friction forces in the model.

Comment: Changing loads are typically called follower forces in contexts other than contact.

Comment: Good explanations. However, my impression is all the stiffness terms are related to the applied force, stress, and displacement, which is the basis of defining the stiffness matrix. Am I missing something that is directly related to the change in material geometric properties (A, I)?